# Visual swatches for attribute with input type multiselect

Tags: magento2, attributes, swatches, color-swatches

In Magento 2.1.1 CE **visual swatches** works with select-type attributes out of box, but not witth multiselect.

Is there any simple way to make it work also with multiselect-type?

Can it be achieved by some configuration or small modification of core files? Or is it more complicated?

Comment: As a workaround, i map the select swatch text value with the multiselect value.

Comment: thats a good point, but are they editable from admin html?

Comment: I edit them from backoffice and use cutom code for FO

Comment: @frank, can you please add your changes here as solution?

Comment: I also want to make multiselect in visual swatch type attribute, Is there any solution for this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Let me preface this by saying the solution below is far more invasive than I initially thought it would have needed to be. Most notably the total overwrite of `Magento_Swatches/js/product-attributes`. The code below was testing and functioned on Magento 2.2.4.

> Model/Swatch.php
>   This class just holds the constant values for the new frontend input types

```
<?php

namespace Pmclain\MultiSelectSwatch\Model;

class Swatch
{
    const SWATCH_MULTISELECT_TYPE_TEXTUAL_ATTRIBUTE_FRONTEND_INPUT = 'swatch_multiselect_text';
    const SWATCH_MULTISELECT_TYPE_VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE_FRONTEND_INPUT = 'swatch_multiselect_visual';
}
```

> Observer/AddMultiSelectSwatchType.php
>   The observer will add the new frontend input type to the product attribute edit form.

```
<?php

namespace Pmclain\MultiSelectSwatch\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Manager;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddMultiSelectSwatchType implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $moduleManager;

    public function __construct(Manager $moduleManager)
    {
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        if (!$this->moduleManager->isOutputEnabled('Pmclain_MultiSelectSwatch')) {
            return;
        }

        $response = $observer->getEvent()->getResponse();
        $types = $response->getTypes();
        $types[] = [
            'value' => \Pmclain\MultiSelectSwatch\Model\Swatch::SWATCH_MULTISELECT_TYPE_VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE_FRONTEND_INPUT,
            'label' => __('Visual Swatch - Multiselect'),
            'hide_fields' => [
                'is_unique',
                'is_required',
                'frontend_class',
                '_scope',
                '_default_value',
            ],
        ];
        $types[] = [
            'value' => \Pmclain\MultiSelectSwatch\Model\Swatch::SWATCH_MULTISELECT_TYPE_TEXTUAL_ATTRIBUTE_FRONTEND_INPUT,
            'label' => __('Text Swatch - Multiselect'),
            'hide_fields' => [
                'is_unique',
                'is_required',
                'frontend_class',
                '_scope',
                '_default_value',
            ],
        ];

        $response->setTypes($types);
    }
}
```

> etc/adminhtml/events.xml
>   Register the observer created above.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="adminhtml_product_attribute_types">
        <observer name="multiselect_swatch_attribute_type" instance="Pmclain\MultiSelectSwatch\Observer\AddMultiSelectSwatchType" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> view/adminhtml/web/js/product-attributes.js
>   Add the frontend input values to the product attribute javascript. I couldn't find a clean way for doing this via a mixin, so this is a full rewrite of the core javascript.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/prompt',
    'uiRegistry',
    'collapsable'
], function ($, alert, prompt, rg) {
    'use strict';

    return function (optionConfig) {
        var swatchProductAttributes = {
                frontendInput: $('#frontend_input'),
                isFilterable: $('#is_filterable'),
                isFilterableInSearch: $('#is_filterable_in_search'),
                backendType: $('#backend_type'),
                usedForSortBy: $('#used_for_sort_by'),
                frontendClass: $('#frontend_class'),
                isWysiwygEnabled: $('#is_wysiwyg_enabled'),
                isHtmlAllowedOnFront: $('#is_html_allowed_on_front'),
                isRequired: $('#is_required'),
                isUnique: $('#is_unique'),
                defaultValueText: $('#default_value_text'),
                defaultValueTextarea: $('#default_value_textarea'),
                defaultValueDate: $('#default_value_date'),
                defaultValueYesno: $('#default_value_yesno'),
                isGlobal: $('#is_global'),
                useProductImageForSwatch: $('#use_product_image_for_swatch'),
                updateProductPreviewImage: $('#update_product_preview_image'),
                usedInProductListing: $('#used_in_product_listing'),
                isVisibleOnFront: $('#is_visible_on_front'),
                position: $('#position'),
                attrTabsFront: $('#product_attribute_tabs_front'),

                get tabsFront() {
                    return this.attrTabsFront.length ? this.attrTabsFront.closest('li') : $('#front_fieldset-wrapper');
                },
                selectFields: ['select', 'multiselect', 'price', 'swatch_text', 'swatch_visual', 'swatch_multiselect_text', 'swatch_multiselect_visual'],

                toggleApplyVisibility: function (select) {
                    if ($(select).val() === 1) {
                        $(select).next('select').removeClass('no-display');
                        $(select).next('select').removeClass('ignore-validate');
                    } else {
                        $(select).next('select').addClass('no-display');
                        $(select).next('select').addClass('ignore-validate');
                        $(select).next('select option:selected').each(function () {
                            this.selected = false;
                        });
                    }
                },

                checkOptionsPanelVisibility: function () {
                    var selectOptionsPanel = $('#manage-options-panel'),
                        visualOptionsPanel = $('#swatch-visual-options-panel'),
                        textOptionsPanel = $('#swatch-text-options-panel');

                    this._hidePanel(selectOptionsPanel);
                    this._hidePanel(visualOptionsPanel);
                    this._hidePanel(textOptionsPanel);

                    switch (this.frontendInput.val()) {
                        case 'swatch_visual':
                        case 'swatch_multiselect_visual':
                            this._showPanel(visualOptionsPanel);
                            break;

                        case 'swatch_text':
                        case 'swatch_multiselect_text':
                            this._showPanel(textOptionsPanel);
                            break;

                        case 'select':
                        case 'multiselect':
                            this._showPanel(selectOptionsPanel);
                            break;
                    }
                },

                bindAttributeInputType: function () {
                    this.checkOptionsPanelVisibility();
                    this.switchDefaultValueField();

                    if (!~$.inArray(this.frontendInput.val(), this.selectFields)) {
                        // not in array
                        this.isFilterable.selectedIndex = 0;
                        this._disable(this.isFilterable);
                        this._disable(this.isFilterableInSearch);
                    } else {
                        // in array
                        this._enable(this.isFilterable);
                        this._enable(this.isFilterableInSearch);
                        this.backendType.val('int');
                    }

                    if (this.frontendInput.val() === 'multiselect' ||
                        this.frontendInput.val() === 'gallery' ||
                        this.frontendInput.val() === 'textarea'
                    ) {
                        this._disable(this.usedForSortBy);
                    } else {
                        this._enable(this.usedForSortBy);
                    }

                    if (this.frontendInput.val() === 'swatch_text') {
                        $('.swatch-text-field-0').addClass('required-option');
                    } else {
                        $('.swatch-text-field-0').removeClass('required-option');
                    }

                    this.setRowVisibility(this.isWysiwygEnabled, false);
                    this.setRowVisibility(this.isHtmlAllowedOnFront, false);

                    switch (this.frontendInput.val()) {
                        case 'textarea':
                            this.setRowVisibility(this.isWysiwygEnabled, true);

                            if (this.isWysiwygEnabled.val() === '0') {
                                this._enable(this.isHtmlAllowedOnFront);
                            }
                            this.frontendClass.val('');
                            this._disable(this.frontendClass);
                            break;

                        case 'text':
                            this.setRowVisibility(this.isHtmlAllowedOnFront, true);
                            this._enable(this.frontendClass);
                            break;

                        case 'select':
                        case 'multiselect':
                            this.setRowVisibility(this.isHtmlAllowedOnFront, true);
                            this.frontendClass.val('');
                            this._disable(this.frontendClass);
                            break;
                        default:
                            this.frontendClass.val('');
                            this._disable(this.frontendClass);
                    }

                    this.switchIsFilterable();
                },

                switchIsFilterable: function () {
                    if (this.isFilterable.selectedIndex === 0) {
                        this._disable(this.position);
                    } else {
                        this._enable(this.position);
                    }
                },

                /**
                 * @this {swatchProductAttributes}
                 */
                switchDefaultValueField: function () {
                    var currentValue = this.frontendInput.val(),
                        defaultValueTextVisibility = false,
                        defaultValueTextareaVisibility = false,
                        defaultValueDateVisibility = false,
                        defaultValueYesnoVisibility = false,
                        scopeVisibility = true,
                        useProductImageForSwatch = false,
                        defaultValueUpdateImage = false,
                        optionDefaultInputType = '',
                        isFrontTabHidden = false,
                        thing = this;

                    if (!this.frontendInput.length) {
                        return;
                    }

                    switch (currentValue) {
                        case 'select':
                            optionDefaultInputType = 'radio';
                            break;

                        case 'multiselect':
                            optionDefaultInputType = 'checkbox';
                            break;

                        case 'date':
                            defaultValueDateVisibility = true;
                            break;

                        case 'boolean':
                            defaultValueYesnoVisibility = true;
                            break;

                        case 'textarea':
                            defaultValueTextareaVisibility = true;
                            break;

                        case 'media_image':
                            defaultValueTextVisibility = false;
                            break;

                        case 'price':
                            scopeVisibility = false;
                            break;

                        case 'swatch_visual':
                        case 'swatch_multiselect_visual':
                            useProductImageForSwatch = true;
                            defaultValueUpdateImage = true;
                            defaultValueTextVisibility = false;
                            break;

                        case 'swatch_text':
                        case 'swatch_multiselect_text':
                            useProductImageForSwatch = false;
                            defaultValueUpdateImage = true;
                            defaultValueTextVisibility = false;
                            break;
                        default:
                            defaultValueTextVisibility = true;
                            break;
                    }

                    delete optionConfig.hiddenFields['swatch_visual'];
                    delete optionConfig.hiddenFields['swatch_text'];

                    if (currentValue === 'media_image') {
                        this.tabsFront.hide();
                        this.setRowVisibility(this.isRequired, false);
                        this.setRowVisibility(this.isUnique, false);
                        this.setRowVisibility(this.frontendClass, false);
                    } else if (optionConfig.hiddenFields[currentValue]) {
                        $.each(optionConfig.hiddenFields[currentValue], function (key, option) {
                            switch (option) {
                                case '_front_fieldset':
                                    thing.tabsFront.hide();
                                    isFrontTabHidden = true;
                                    break;

                                case '_default_value':
                                    defaultValueTextVisibility = false;
                                    defaultValueTextareaVisibility = false;
                                    defaultValueDateVisibility = false;
                                    defaultValueYesnoVisibility = false;
                                    break;

                                case '_scope':
                                    scopeVisibility = false;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    thing.setRowVisibility($('#' + option), false);
                            }
                        });

                        if (!isFrontTabHidden) {
                            thing.tabsFront.show();
                        }

                    } else {
                        this.tabsFront.show();
                        this.showDefaultRows();
                    }

                    this.setRowVisibility(this.defaultValueText, defaultValueTextVisibility);
                    this.setRowVisibility(this.defaultValueTextarea, defaultValueTextareaVisibility);
                    this.setRowVisibility(this.defaultValueDate, defaultValueDateVisibility);
                    this.setRowVisibility(this.defaultValueYesno, defaultValueYesnoVisibility);
                    this.setRowVisibility(this.isGlobal, scopeVisibility);

                    /* swatch attributes */
                    this.setRowVisibility(this.useProductImageForSwatch, useProductImageForSwatch);
                    this.setRowVisibility(this.updateProductPreviewImage, defaultValueUpdateImage);

                    $('input[name=\'default[]\']').each(function () {
                        $(this).attr('type', optionDefaultInputType);
                    });
                },

                /**
                 * @this {swatchProductAttributes}
                 */
                showDefaultRows: function () {
                    this.setRowVisibility(this.isRequired, true);
                    this.setRowVisibility(this.isUnique, true);
                    this.setRowVisibility(this.frontendClass, true);
                },

                /**
                 * @param {Object} el
                 * @param {Boolean} isVisible
                 * @this {swatchProductAttributes}
                 */
                setRowVisibility: function (el, isVisible) {
                    if (isVisible) {
                        el.show();
                        el.closest('.field').show();
                    } else {
                        el.hide();
                        el.closest('.field').hide();
                    }
                },

                /**
                 * @param {Object} el
                 * @this {swatchProductAttributes}
                 */
                _disable: function (el) {
                    el.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                },

                /**
                 * @param {Object} el
                 * @this {swatchProductAttributes}
                 */
                _enable: function (el) {
                    if (!el.attr('readonly')) {
                        el.removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                },

                /**
                 * @param {Object} el
                 * @this {swatchProductAttributes}
                 */
                _showPanel: function (el) {
                    el.closest('.fieldset').show();
                    this._render(el.attr('id'));
                },

                /**
                 * @param {Object} el
                 * @this {swatchProductAttributes}
                 */
                _hidePanel: function (el) {
                    el.closest('.fieldset').hide();
                },

                /**
                 * @param {String} id
                 * @this {swatchProductAttributes}
                 */
                _render: function (id) {
                    rg.get(id, function () {
                        $('#' + id).trigger('render');
                    });
                },

                /**
                 * @param {String} promptMessage
                 * @this {swatchProductAttributes}
                 */
                saveAttributeInNewSet: function (promptMessage) {

                    prompt({
                        content: promptMessage,
                        actions: {

                            /**
                             * @param {String} val
                             * @this {actions}
                             */
                            confirm: function (val) {
                                var rules = ['required-entry', 'validate-no-html-tags'],
                                    newAttributeSetNameInputId = $('#new_attribute_set_name'),
                                    editForm = $('#edit_form'),
                                    newAttributeSetName = val,
                                    i;

                                if (!newAttributeSetName) {
                                    return;
                                }

                                for (i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
                                    if (!$.validator.methods[rules[i]](newAttributeSetName)) {
                                        alert({
                                            content: $.validator.messages[rules[i]]
                                        });

                                        return;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (newAttributeSetNameInputId.length) {
                                    newAttributeSetNameInputId.val(newAttributeSetName);
                                } else {
                                    editForm.append(new Element('input', {
                                            type: 'hidden',
                                            id: newAttributeSetNameInputId,
                                            name: 'new_attribute_set_name',
                                            value: newAttributeSetName
                                        })
                                    );
                                }
                                // Temporary solution will replaced after refactoring of attributes functionality
                                editForm.triggerHandler('save');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

        $(function () {
            $('#frontend_input').bind('change', function () {
                swatchProductAttributes.bindAttributeInputType();
            });
            $('#is_filterable').bind('change', function () {
                swatchProductAttributes.switchIsFilterable();
            });

            swatchProductAttributes.bindAttributeInputType();

            // @todo: refactor collapsable component
            $('.attribute-popup .collapse, [data-role="advanced_fieldset-content"]')
                .collapsable()
                .collapse('hide');
        });

        window.saveAttributeInNewSet = swatchProductAttributes.saveAttributeInNewSet;
        window.toggleApplyVisibility = swatchProductAttributes.toggleApplyVisibility;
    };
});
```

> view/adminhtml/web/js/type-change.js
>   Add the ability for switching between multiselect, visual swatch multiselect, and text swatch multiselect.

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $(function () {

        $('select#frontend_input:disabled').each(function () {
            var select = $(this),
                currentValue = select.find('option:selected').val(),
                enabledTypes = ['multiselect', 'swatch_multiselect_visual', 'swatch_multiselect_text'],
                warning = $('<label>')
                    .hide()
                    .text($.mage.__('These changes affect all related products.'))
                    .addClass('mage-error')
                    .attr({
                        generated: true, for: select.attr('id')
                    }),

                toggleWarning = function () {
                    if (select.find('option:selected').val() === currentValue) {
                        warning.hide();
                    } else {
                        warning.show();
                    }
                },

                removeOption = function () {
                    if (!~enabledTypes.indexOf($(this).val())) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                };

            if (!~enabledTypes.indexOf(currentValue)) {
                return;
            }

            select.removeAttr('disabled').find('option').each(removeOption);

            select.after(warning).on('change', toggleWarning);
        });
    });
});
```

> view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js
>   Register the rewrite of the core product attribute javascript above.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            swatchesProductAttributes: 'Pmclain_MultiSelectSwatch/js/product-attributes'
        }
    }
};
```

> view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/attribute/js.phtml
>   For adding all the javascript about on the attribute edit forms.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "swatchesProductAttributes": {
                "hiddenFields": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ json_encode($this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->getAttributeHiddenFields()) ?>
            },
            "swatchesTypeChange": { },
            "Pmclain_MultiSelectSwatch/js/type-change": { }
        }
    }
</script>
```

> view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_attribute_edit_popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="admin-1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="attribute_edit_js">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Pmclain_MultiSelectSwatch::catalog/product/attribute/js.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_attribute_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="admin-1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="attribute_edit_js">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Pmclain_MultiSelectSwatch::catalog/product/attribute/js.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Plugin/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Save.php
>   Handle the new frontend types when saving product attributes.

```
<?php

namespace Pmclain\MultiSelectSwatch\Plugin\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute;

use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Swatches\Model\Swatch;
use Pmclain\MultiSelectSwatch\Model\Swatch as MultiselectSwatch;

class Save
{
    public function beforeDispatch(Attribute\Save $subject, RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $data = $request->getPostValue();
        if (isset($data['frontend_input'])) {
            switch ($data['frontend_input']) {
                case MultiselectSwatch::SWATCH_MULTISELECT_TYPE_VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE_FRONTEND_INPUT:
                    $data[Swatch::SWATCH_INPUT_TYPE_KEY] = Swatch::SWATCH_INPUT_TYPE_VISUAL;
                    $data['frontend_input'] = 'multiselect';
                    $request->setPostValue($data);
                    break;
                case MultiselectSwatch::SWATCH_MULTISELECT_TYPE_TEXTUAL_ATTRIBUTE_FRONTEND_INPUT:
                    $data[Swatch::SWATCH_INPUT_TYPE_KEY] = Swatch::SWATCH_INPUT_TYPE_TEXT;
                    $data['use_product_image_for_swatch'] = 0;
                    $data['frontend_input'] = 'multiselect';
                    $request->setPostValue($data);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return [$request];
    }
}
```

> Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/Form.php
>   Ensure the proper frontend type is pre-selected when loading an existing attribute with the multiselect swatch type.

```
<?php

namespace Pmclain\MultiSelectSwatch\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit;

use Magento\Swatches\Model\Swatch;

class Form extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Form
{
    public function addValues($values)
    {
        if (!is_array($values)) {
            return $this;
        }
        $values = array_merge(
            $values,
            $this->getAdditionalData($values)
        );
        if (isset($values['frontend_input']) && 'multiselect' == $values['frontend_input']
            && isset($values[Swatch::SWATCH_INPUT_TYPE_KEY])
        ) {
            $values['frontend_input'] = 'swatch_multiselect_' . $values[Swatch::SWATCH_INPUT_TYPE_KEY];
        }
        return parent::addValues($values);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, it seems for a quite complicated thing...

Comment: Getting the admin form working to create new multiselect swatch attributes was extremely involved. If you create the multiselect swatch attribute with a Setup|Upgrade script you can ditch all the javascript and it just works. I put the above code on Github in case anyone wants to quickly copy/test it. https://github.com/pmclain/module-multiselect-swatch

Comment: @Pmclain
I have downloaded this module from github, but it is not working fine for me.
Issue: Use in Layered Navigation = Filterable (with results)
I have configured above setting in my attribute, still it is not showing on category page (layered navigation filter options). 
Please help in this issue.

Comment: @Pmclain I tried your code from Github. I can create a visual swatch multiselect attribute but attribute option section does showing. seems hidden all the time. Could you help me to overcome this issue?